# Import homemade package without duplicating name

Tags: python, pypi

I've built a package which I distributed through PyPI.

The upload, download, installation, and the package itself, all work fine. My problem is that in order to run it I need to call the package name twice, which I want to avoid.

I want it to go like this:

```
import package_name

package_name.do_stuff()
```

But it only works like this:

```
from package_name import module_name

module_name.do_stuff()
```

Rather than having `package_name` be the same as `module_name`, or have two different names, I just one the one. I suppose its because of the way the project folder is structured, like so:

```
package_name/
|
- setup.py
- requirements.txt
- package_name/
  |
   - __init.py__
   - module_name.py
- dist
- README etc
```

I guess what I'm asking is how can I structure my project folder so that I get neat usage in the form of:

```
pip install package_name

import package_name

package_name.do_stuff()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be performed by importing `module_name` in `package_name/package_name/__init__.py`.

Given your exact structure, with:

```py
# package_name/package_name/module_name.py

class Foo:
    pass
```

```py
# package_name/package_name/__init__.py

from package_name.module_name import Foo
```

Then you should be able to perform

```
from package_name import Foo
```

from e.g. `package_name/test.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `module_name.py`? Just put your code in `__init__.py` and it will be accessible from the "top level" of the module.

Comment: .. and if you want to split the code into multiple files / modules, see Tom's answer.

Comment: I would argue that in many situations, yes you need `module_name.py`. Larger projects will benefit from multiple files, each with their own fitting name to denote the contents. That said - this is indeed a solution to the problem, and it works for small projects.